# Как делать, чтобы с помощью JRadiobutton вывести тексе

Tags: java, gui

вопрос такой. Есть название несколько песен. Надо делать так, что если выбрал первую песню и запустил то вывел текст какой-то песни.
В этом деле еще новичок и не знаю как делать. Я вставлю текст и программа выводит этот текст для всех песен, а надо, чтобы для отдельных песен был отдельный текст.
Прошу не сказать "Да что тут сложного все просто и т.д.". Я только вчера начал изучать GUI. 
Ладно вот код։

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Grafika extends JFrame {
    JButton button = new JButton("Запустить");
    JTextField text = new JTextField("Выберите песню");
    JLabel input = new JLabel("Все песни");
    JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Песня 1");
    JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Песня 2");
    JRadioButton radio3 = new JRadioButton("Песня 3");
    JRadioButton radio4 = new JRadioButton("Песня 4");
    JRadioButton radio5 = new JRadioButton("Песня 5");
    JRadioButton radio6 = new JRadioButton("Песня 6");
    JRadioButton radio7 = new JRadioButton("Песня 7");

    public Grafika(){
        super("Lyrics");
        this.setBounds(200, 200, 450, 500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(Grafika.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5, 7, 7 ));

    container.add(input);
    container.add(text);
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(radio1);
    group.add(radio2);
    group.add(radio3);
    group.add(radio4);
    group.add(radio5);
    group.add(radio6);
    group.add(radio7);
    container.add(radio1);
    radio1.setSelected(true);
    container.add(radio2);
    container.add(radio3);
    container.add(radio4);
    container.add(radio5);
    container.add(radio6);
    container.add(radio7);
    text.setEditable(false);

    button.addActionListener(new ButtonEventListener());
    container.add(button);
    }

    class ButtonEventListener implements  ActionListener{
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Текст какой-то песни", "Текст", 
        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
```

Comment: Читайте про паттерн MVC. Именно его и надо использовать для swing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте мапу (радио-кнопка, текст). Занесите туда все кнопки (можно ограничиться номерами).

В ButtonEventListener при нажатии на кнопку проверяйте какая радио-точка выбрана и берите из мапы текст для неё и показывайте.

Comment: спс брат помог)))